# Can Breeze WebAPI expose ODATA

Tags: breeze

Can a Breeeze ApiController support ODATA clients for read-only access, now that Microsoft have added ODATA support for WebAPI?

Answer (score 1):

We are working on doing exactly this.  Hopefully, we should have a release out with this ability within the next two weeks.  I will post back here when it is available.