# BreezeController as OData Endpoint

Tags: odata, breeze

I'd like to be able to have my BreezeController on the server side also be accessible by standard OData clients. I saw there was a question almost a year ago that was answered saying this was coming to breeze [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225573/can-breeze-webapi-expose-odata). However, when I point an OData client (such as LinqPad or Excel) to my server it has an issue since the metadata isn't correct. This is even after changing the metadata action name on the controller to "$metadata". Am I correct in believing that a Breeze WebApi2 controller can act as an odata endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hang in there, @cobywhite. We're about to release a Web API 2 OData sample that will show you how. Maybe by end of this week or top of next week.

You will have to make a small change on the OData server to get it to deliver the proper metadata. Are you able to do that?

As for reusing the "BreezeController" ... that's going to be tricky.  OData is very particular about having its own controllers. I think you'll have to write those too. Make sure you **don't put any business logic in any of your controllers**. You shouldn't be doing that under any circumstances but now it will be imperative.

**Always delegate to a repository or unit-of-work-and-repositories**. The controllers should focus exclusively on their roles as vehicles and gatekeepers for communication with clients.

Comment: Will the example be built upon using a repository or unit-of-work-and-repository?

Comment: Sadly not. This sample is a joint effort with the Microsoft team. I asked about DI and repos. "They" decided that such animals would be "too complicated" <sigh/>. I'd rather have Microsoft on my team than fight this battle. I suppose if you can ask the question you can solve it yourself. We put an apologetic note in the documentation.

Comment: Just to clarify on the BreezeController bit, even though "The metadata document returned from a Breeze WebApi controller extends the OData standard" (from [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata)) there isn't a way to have a Breeze WebApi controller feed conventional OData clients?

Comment: I have no idea what that sentence means and I just removed it from the docs. As for your question, the answer is "not to my knowledge."  That's a limitation of Web API, not a BreezeController per se. I have no reason to believe you can mix and match Web API controllers and Web API OData controllers. Payloads are definitely different. If you need both, keep controllers thin and use repos. You won't learn how from our sample and its stupid tedious to write those OData controllers but not hard

Comment: Any word on these samples?  I'd really like to have some sample of Breeze controllers implementing OData.  Are you saying this is not possible?

Comment: That is correct ... AFAIK it is not literally possible for them to have the same controllers. This is **not a limitation of Breeze *per se***. It's the way the Web API is designed. If you want to support both Breeze and non-Breeze-OData clients, you'll need separate controllers. That sounds harsh but it doesn't have to be. The key to success is keeping all controllers lightweight. They should be dispatchers with little/no business logic. Wrappers essentially that simply mediate the protocol differences. Keep the real logic in repositories and units-of-work

Comment: Could you provide a link to this example please?